# How to control the position of disconnected nodes with cose-bilkent layout

Tags: javascript, node.js, cytoscape.js

I'm working with compound graphs library `cytoscape.js` and doing a layout with `cose-bilkent`. I know the option `tile` means whether to tile disconnected nodes.
But how does the layout `cose-bilkent` tile the disconnected nodes?

Take a look at my screenshot :
[image: disconnected nodes position]

The disconnected nodes position at the upper right corner of the canvas, and far away from the connected nodes, which looks not good.

I expect more reasonable control over the position of disconnected nodes. For example, is it possible to layout disconnected nodes on the bottom of connected nodes? What I need like the following screenshot :
[image]

Demo

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){

    var cy = window.cy = cytoscape({
     container: document.getElementById('cy'),

     layout: {
      name: 'cose-bilkent'
     },

     style: [
      {
       selector: 'node',
       style: {
        'background-color': '#ad1a66',
        'label':'data(n)'
       }
      },

      {
       selector: ':parent',
       style: {
        'background-opacity': 0.333
       }
      },

      {
       selector: "node.cy-expand-collapse-collapsed-node",
       style: {
        "background-color": "darkblue",
        "shape": "rectangle"
       }
      },

      {
       selector: 'edge',
       style: {
        'width': 1,
        'line-color': '#ad1a66',
        'curve-style' : 'bezier',//haystack
      'line-color': 'rgb(168, 168, 168)',
      'target-arrow-color': 'rgb(168, 168, 168)',
            'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle'
       }
      },

      {
       selector: 'edge.meta',
       style: {
        'width': 2,
        'line-color': 'red'
       }
      },

      {
       selector: ':selected',
       style: {
         "border-width": 3,
        "border-color": '#DAA520'
       }
      }
     ],

     elements: {"nodes":[{"data":{"id":"n_0","n":"n0"}},{"data":{"id":"n_1","n":"n1"}},{"data":{"id":"n_2","n":"n2"}},{"data":{"id":"n_3","n":"n3"}},{"data":{"id":"n_4","n":"n4"}},{"data":{"id":"n_5","n":"n5"}},{"data":{"id":"n_6","n":"n6"}},{"data":{"id":"n_7","n":"n7"}},{"data":{"id":"n_8","n":"n8"}},{"data":{"id":"n_0","n":"External Network"},"grabbable":false},{"data":{"id":"n_10","n":"n10"}},{"data":{"id":"n_11","n":"n11"}},{"data":{"id":"n_12","n":"n12"}},{"data":{"id":"n_13","n":"n13"}},{"data":{"id":"n_14","n":"n14"}},{"data":{"id":"n_15","n":"n15"}},{"data":{"id":"n_16","n":"n16"}},{"data":{"id":"n_17","n":"n17"}},{"data":{"id":"n_18","n":"n18"}},{"data":{"id":"n_19","n":"n19"}},{"data":{"id":"n_20","n":"n20"}},{"data":{"id":"n_21","n":"n21"}},{"data":{"id":"n_22","n":"n22"}},{"data":{"id":"n_23","n":"n23"}},{"data":{"id":"n_24","n":"n24"}},{"data":{"id":"n_25","n":"n25"}},{"data":{"id":"n_26","n":"n26"}},{"data":{"id":"n_27","n":"n27"}},{"data":{"id":"n_28","n":"n28"}},{"data":{"id":"n_29","n":"n29"}}],"edges":[{"data":{"source":"n_0","target":"n_1"}},{"data":{"source":"n_0","target":"n_7"}},{"data":{"source":"n_1","target":"n_7"}},{"data":{"source":"n_7","target":"n_0"}}]}
    });
   });
```

```css
body {
    font-family: helvetica neue, helvetica, liberation sans, arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
   }

   #cy {
    z-index: 999;
    width: 85%;
    height: 85%;
    float: left;
   }

   h1 {
    opacity: 0.5;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape@3.1.0/dist/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape-cose-bilkent@4.0.0/cytoscape-cose-bilkent.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cy"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is old question, but Im using this extension that has some utilities like packing components that could be what you are looking for (if still needed)

https://github.com/iVis-at-Bilkent/cytoscape.js-layout-utilities